# Woo-Commerce new order email no style attached

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

This one is baffling me, but when a new order is created the email is sent to the customer and a new order email is created but none of the order details are being sent see image:
[image]

I've gone through the templates and everything looks fine, when I click on preview template everything also looks fine.

I've updated plugins and still everytime I create a new order I just get this bare email with no details

It's like the top half of the email is missing

This is how the order should look like
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins other than the base Woocommerce plugin and tested? I suspect either something is interfering with a filter/hook or overriding the template altogether despite what you see in preview.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't as straight forward as a plugin that was overwriting another but just some plugins needed to be deactivated and then activated and the problem seemed to go away.